# select in react doesn't update the label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, state, setstate

When i implemented, it worked fine :

```
 constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state={
          selectedValue :'' ,
}}
```

Dropdown Code :

```
            <select
            className="ui dropdown"
          value={this.state.selectedValue || ''}
          onChange={e =>
            this.setState({
              selectedValue: e.target.value,
              validationError:
                e.target.value === ""
                  ? "You must select"
                  : ""
            })
          }>
          <option value="">--Select Station--</option>
          {this.state.stationList.map(team => (
            <option key={team.id} value={team.id}>
              {team.station}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

Now on selecting the value label doesn't update on first time, Second time i click it show with previous label selected and on next time click previous last time label displayed

How can i make it work right like normal on select label should update!

see the video here for label error > [video](http://files.fm/u/cdszjt6w)

Comment: Try by changing to functional setState in onChange.

Comment: Your code looks good, i've just created a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-curran-0e8j0) to review it, but its working fine, how do you got this issue could you elaborate?

Comment: @MuhammadAli i have tried it but it didn't worked for me! Thank you

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez yes , i have same code in another file and it works fine and it worked here also fine when it was implemented but now it doesn't! thanks for demo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know it should not work but i tried using

```
forcepdate()
```

it worked with warnings so i did :

```
 value={this.updateFunc(this.state.selectedValue)}
```

and called it like:

```
updateFunc(e){
console(e);
}
```

i don't think is nay right approach but this worked for me now so i go with this,
state doesn't update immediately, idea of using forceUpdate() brought me to this decision.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working well I think their is a problem in your array

check this code on code sandbox

[check the given code](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cdn-rt2ib?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

or you can see this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: ""
    };
  }
  myArray = [
    { id: "1", name: "one" },
    { id: "2", name: "two" },
    { id: "3", name: "three" }
  ];

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectedValue);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>are you listening</h1>
        <select
          className="ui dropdown"
          value={this.state.selectedValue}
          onChange={e =>
            this.setState({
              selectedValue: e.target.value,
              validationError: e.target.value === "" ? "You must select" : ""
            })
          }
        >
          <option value="">--Select Station--</option>
          {this.myArray.map(team => (
            <option key={team.id} value={team.id}>
              {team.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

hope this will help

Comment: still i am facing error in label it doesn't update the label , its working find and shows value in console and perform things means it works , all issue i face is with labels , which go as unchanged on first click and from next time click i see previous state selected

Comment: for which label you are talking about, can you explain a bit about label ? @Ansh

Comment: explain labels ? @AnshVarun

Comment: see if you can understand from this [video] (https://files.fm/u/cdszjt6w)

Comment: Issue i face with is with setState this function does update but not immediately , i used value = {this.forceUpdate(this.state.selectedValue)} which is doing state update for me but still this is something that 1) Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 2)  Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. Eventually forceUpdate() works but not rigth approach